# What should be the package name in main/AndroidManifest.xml when dealing with product flavors?

Tags: android, xml, build.gradle, android-productflavors, package-name

I have two product flavors in my build.gradle which are as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    aaptOptions.setProperty("cruncherEnabled", false)

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 16
        applicationId "com.example.app"
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    def final myApplicationId = 'com.example.app'
    def final appName = 'app'

    productFlavors {
        dev {

            resValue "string", "app_name", appName
            resValue "string", "APIURL", "http://prod.example.com/"
        }
        production {

            resValue "string", "app_name", appName
            resValue "string", "APIURL", "http://test.example.com/"
        }
    }
    buildTypes{
        dtest {
            applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
        }
        dprod{

        }
    }
}



dependencies {
    compile()
    few libraries
}
```

my dev/AndroidManifest.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.app.dev"
    android:installLocation="auto"
    android:versionCode="3"
    android:versionName="3.1">

</manifest>
```

and my production/AndroidManifest.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.app"
    android:installLocation="auto"
    android:versionCode="3"
    android:versionName="3.1">

</manifest>
```

my main/AndroidManifest.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.app"
    android:installLocation="auto"
    android:versionCode="3"
    android:versionName="3.1">
    <application>
          <activity list.. </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I want to install dev and production flavor in the same device, but I am not able to change the package name even when I have set different applicationId. I suspect package name that I mentioned in main manifest is overriding the applicationId from build.gradle in some way or another. I'd appreciate if someone points me in right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than setting that in `productFlavors`, add that in `buildTypes`

Use

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
        // Rest of the code block
    }

    release {
        // your code block
    }
}
```

**Update**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    aaptOptions.setProperty("cruncherEnabled", false)

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 16
        applicationId "com.example.app"
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug{
            applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        dev {

            resValue "string", "app_name", appName
            resValue "string", "APIURL", "http://prod.example.com/"
        }
        production {

            resValue "string", "app_name", appName
            resValue "string", "APIURL", "http://test.example.com/"
        }
    }
}



dependencies {
    compile()
    few libraries
}
```

Comment: And where should I add my other API urls? I have two different API urls for development and production version. Let me update the question again for productFlavors full code

Comment: Did you try what I suggested? It's working perfectly for me. I have 9 flavors in my app.

Comment: It needs APK to be signed, is there any other way developing the apk without signing it just for test?

Comment: Every apk is signed. Debug with default debug key which is automatic.

Comment: I'm getting 8 options in build variant now, and when I try to install dev debug it gets installed, but for installing production debug, it says you will have to uninstall dev debug.

Comment: Can you post complete `build.gradle`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103841/discussion-between-1binary0-and-rohit5k2).

Comment: Please see my update. Replace your build.gradle with this one. Do keep a backup of your's

Comment: Tried your updated solution, but still debug and production buildTypes are overwriting each other.

Comment: I am using similar gradle file and its working for me. But there are two differences. 1. My gradle doesn't have `applicationId` in `defaultConfig` and 2. I have only one manifest file (in main folder). That making these changes.

Comment: Tried that one too, now if dev is installed then it doesn't install prod release, and vice versa.

Comment: I don't understand. We are missing something here because the same thing works for me.